# Aligning Text in Buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="sldkjf", justify=LEFT, padx=130).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Why doesn't the text show in the left, although I set the justify to `left`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are several things to note here: 1) Your question incorrectly states that the text doesn't show in the center. 2) Why do you expect the text to show in the _center_, if you set the justify to the _left_? 3) If you set the `padx` to something that large, then the text is going to be squeezed into the center anyway. Questions must show an honest research effort and attempt to solve the problem. See [ask] and the [help] for more details.

Comment: I meant text to be left, plus whether I had it as padx or width, it didn't justify center in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the `justify` option says this:

> **justify** - When there are multiple lines of text displayed in a widget, this option determines how the lines line up with each other.

You don't have multiple lines, you have a single line.

To get the text to be aligned to the top, bottom, left, or right, you need to use the `anchor` option. This is what the documentation says:

> **anchor** - Specifies how the information in a widget (e.g. text or a bitmap) is to be displayed in the widget. Must be one of the values n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, or center. For example, nw means display the information such that its top-left corner is at the top-left corner of the widget.

So, in your case you should use `anchor="w"`.

You also have the problem that the excessive padding is applied to both sides, in effect squeezing the text to fit in between the 130x padding on the left and the 130px padding on the right. If you remove the padding, the text will be anchored to the left side of the widget.